# Sonarqube 7.9.1 refuses to start after an upgrade from 6.7.7

Tags: java, elasticsearch, sonarqube

The previous version of SQ was 6.7.7 LTS, so i upgraded to 7.9.1 LTS.
I installed a new JDK

```
java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

but still SQ stopped.
This is a snippet of the sonar.log

`````
    2019.08.01 14:50:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating                   temp directory /data/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp
    2019.08.01 14:50:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
    2019.08.01 14:50:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/data/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch]: /data/sonarqube/sonarqube-````7.9.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
    2019.08.01 14:50:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
    2019.08.01 14:50:20 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
    2019.08.01 14:50:20 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
    2019.08.01 14:50:22 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
    2019.08.01 14:50:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
    2019.08.01 14:50:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
    2019.08.01 14:50:22 INFO  app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{GK1cYpSNTM-eycINcVQsOA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}, disconnecting...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Future got interrupted
`````

and a snippet of es.log

```
2019.08.01 14:50:22 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
```

of course i start SQ (and ES) with a non-root user. That’s why i don’t understand the error in es.log

I can't find the solution at all. Please can you help me?

With kind regards, William

Comment: Did you upgrade in place or created a new folder?

Comment: Can you also share the command/script you're using to start SonarQube please?

Comment: @Jeroen, Every time when i upgrade SQ in fact i do a fresh install into a new folder. Then i update the contents of sonar.properties and wrapper.conf. SQ 6.7.7 was sufficient with JDK 8.X, but 7.9.1 requires JDK 11.X or higher. That is why I have installed a new Java.

Comment: @mc1arke, there is a sonar service script in /etc/init.d, so i start with 'service sonar start'. This is the script #!/bin/sh
#
# rc file for SonarQube
#
# chkconfig: 345 96 10
# description: SonarQube system
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sonar
# Required-Start: $network
# Required-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: SonarQube system 
# Description: SonarQube system 
### END INIT INFO

/usr/bin/sonar $*. But when i start directly with ./sonar.sh in the bin directory, i got the same.

Comment: I uncommented wrapper.java.command in wrapper.conf to point to my installed java distribution (I installed JDK 12.0.1, Open JDK Java). Maybe this solves you issue.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, Because I was expecting that JDK 11 to be correct, I had little confidence in installing JDK 12. nevertheless i have installed jdk12 and point my installed java distribution to wrapper.java.command. Still the error in sonar.log and es.log was exactly the same. btw, still there is no ce.log and web.log. I'm wondering about the error in es.log that Elasticsearch cannot run as root.

Comment: If you are sure you are running as a non-root user then I am out of options. Maybe someone in the [Community Forum](https://www.sonarqube.org/community/) can help you.